# DLL library error

Tags: windows-10, dll

The error on Windows 10 x64 constantly pops up when launching applications. `The application failed to start because ShellLink_x64.dll was not found.`

If you click OK, everything works fine, but it’s annoying every time.
I tried googling a solution to this problem, reinstalled the dll library
from https://error-dll.info/file/ShellLink_x64dll, cleaned the registry, and launched the debug mode from command line as here https://windowsbulletin.com/files/dll/future-publishing/lxfdvd145/shelllink-x64-dll.
Nothing helped. I’m thinking of reinstalling the operating system.
Before that, if anyone has had this problem?

Comment: That file seems to be associated with a program called LXFDVD which might be Linux Format DVD, a magazine DVD program. If you have that program installed then uninstalling it might solve your problem.

Comment: Just fyi: ***Never*** download standalone DLLs from random sites. That is inviting disaster.